# how can I fix this issue?

Tags: python

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cars = []
        self.cars_cord = []
        self.lvl_speed = 0

    def random_start(self, mashin):
        y_cord = random.randrange(-230, 280, 75)
        x_cord = 350
        if (x_cord, y_cord) in self.cars_cord and y_cord < 230:
            y_cord *= -1
        mashin.goto(x_cord, y_cord)

    def create_car(self):
        car = Turtle(shape="square")
        car.penup()
        car.shapesize(stretch_len=2, stretch_wid=1)
        car.color(COLORS[random.randint(0, len(COLORS) - 1)])
        self.random_start(car)
        self.cars.append(car)
        self.cars_cord.append((car.xcor(), car.ycor()))

    def move(self):
        for car in self.cars:
            speed = -10
            new_x = car.xcor() + speed + random.randrange(-10, -1) + self.lvl_speed
            car.goto(new_x, car.ycor())

    def remove_cars(self):
        for car in list(self.cars):
            if car.xcor() < -500:
                self.cars.remove(car)
                self.cars_cord.remove((car.xcor(), car.ycor()))

    def lvl_up(self):
        self.lvl_speed -= 2
```

Here is the error:

```
   self.cars_cord.remove((car.xcor(), car.ycor()))
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I just wanna remove the unused objects from the list so the memory usage to be at the minimum and I'm really new to coding.

Comment: BTW, a list probably isn't the ideal data structure for this. If you care more about speed, you probably want a 2d array; if you care more about memory usage and the map is fairly sparse (most coordinates unused), you might want a dictionary instead of a list. Searching through lists to find matching items is slow (O(n)), whereas dictionary lookups are basically amortized constant-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a car you add its coordinates to `cars_cord`:

```
        self.cars_cord.append((car.xcor(), car.ycor()))
```

and when you move a car you updated its coordinates in the car object:

```
            car.goto(new_x, car.ycor())
```

But you never go back to update the coordinates you added to `cars_cord`. So when you try to remove it with

```
   self.cars_cord.remove((car.xcor(), car.ycor()))
```

the x coordinate won't match what was added in `cars_cord`, and you get the error.

You should either update `cars_cord` when cars are moved, rethink the need for that list of coordinates at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot now I get it what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your issue stems from the car moving after you already added it to the list.

In general, unless it is necessary, creating two different lists for attributes of the same mutable object is problematic. It requires synchronizing the attributes, in this case the coordinates, with the same object. Moving it will require changing the coordinates in the list.

I highly suggest storing only one list with cars, and not the coordinates, getting the coordinates from the cars themselves.